# Ajax PUT request executed as GET

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, put

Im trying to make an ajax **cross-origin** *PUT* request:

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:jsonData,
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        ...
       });
```

But it is sent as GET and fails with

> "Incorrect request type. Must be PUT."

any help?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Comment: what if you change `dataType:'jsonp'` to `dataType:'json'`?

Comment: fails due to cross-origin access

Comment: are you passing jsonData as object or as string? make sure you did it this way: `JSON.stringify(jsonData)`

Comment: thank you for remarking that but it still sent as GET instead of PUT and this is this main problem

Comment: just figured out JSONP can't send PUT request but just GET.
see this [link](http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/jsonp-how-does-it-work/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the type should be written as type:'POST' or type:'GET'